# Pra que serve e qual é a diferença entre as opções prefer-dist e prefer-source no Composer?

Tags: composer

No Composer, quando vamos instalar a biblioteca, podemos adicionar como argumento de instalação as opções `--prefer-source` ou `--prefer-dist`.

Eu gostaria de saber o que cada uma faz e/ou se existe diferença entre ambas.

Exemplo

```
 composer install --prefer-dist
```

Exemplo:

```
composer install --prefer-source
```

Comment: Antes que me perguntem se pesquisei no Google: Meu objetivo é ter o conteúdo em português.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Eu gostaria de saber o que cada uma faz e/ou se existe diferença entre
>   ambas.

Essas opções são referentes a como o composer irá baixar e gerenciar as dependências dentro do seu diretório vendor.

`--prefer-dist` dará preferência ao pacote de distribuição daquela dependência caso disponível. É a opção padrão caso você esteja referenciando no seu composer.json uma versão estável daquele pacote.

Por exemplo, ao criar uma *tag* e um release dentro de um repositório do GitHub, essa *tag* terá um *zip* correspondente para aquela versão e a partir desse *zip* o composer irá instalar sua dependência. Essa opção é a mais rápida para se instalar.

`--prefer-source` dará preferência ao download do repositório do código fonte em si, efetuando um `git clone` daquele repositório. Essa opção é interessante caso você esteja trabalhando com um pacote em desenvolvimento e deseja atualizar o conteúdo com *vendor* posteriormente. Ele acaba sendo mais lento pois além do código da aplicação, é baixado também o repositório do projeto.

Mais informações podem ser consultadas na [documentação do composer<sup>en</sup>](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install).

Comment: Caramba! Raspando! Faltando 1 hora pra acabar a recompensa!

Answer (score 3):

--prefer-dist seria a versão de distribuição, uma versão do produto, um 'stable', por exemplo.

--prefer-source seria como baixar o código fonte daquele projeto, o código mais recente, uma versão de desenvolvimento do produto.